# C#: SMTP-сервер - таймаут получения команды

Tags: c#, сокет, smtp

Ситуация: к моему СМТП-серверу подключается клиент(**EHLO**), далее идет диалог (**MAIL,RCPT,BDAT**), потом прощание (**QUIT**). Через время клиент (этот) опять подключается, *почему-то не дает никаких команд*, у меня появляется **таймаут ожидания команды от клиента**.

**Вопрос:**

Как правильно в таком случае я должен поступить:

- продолжать ждать команды от клиента?
- "разрубить" соединение с этим клиентом?
  или что-то еще?

**Спасибо.**

Вот код получения данных от клиента (клиентских команд):

```
 private string ReadLine()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (clientSocket.Available > 0)
                    {
                         byte[] currByte = new byte[1];
                        int countRecieved = clientSocket.Receive(currByte, 1, SocketFlags.None);

                         ///.. код обработки команды и отправка ответа клиента

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        l.Write("clientSocket.Available: " + clientSocket.Available.ToString());
                        //---- Time out stuff -----------------------//
                        if (DateTime.Now.Ticks > lastDataTime + ((long)(60000)) * 10000)
                        {
                            l.Write("ERROR: Read timeout: " + (((long)(60000)) * 10000).ToString());
                           // throw new Exception("Read timeout");
                           // return ""; // ???
                        }
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        //------------------------------------------//
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                l.Write("EROR ReadLine(): " + x.ToString());
                throw new Exception( x.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, ИМХО, на данный вопрос нет однозначно правильного ответа. Многое зависит от контекста использования сервера.

Я бы предложил разрывать соединение если за определённое время "молчун" не начал "диалог". В противном случае возможен вариант DOS/DDOS атаки на ваш сервер путём подключения к вашему серверу большого числа "молчаливых" клиентов. (скажем миллион входящих подключений) И, даже если у вас много памяти и на все объекты хранящие активные соединения у вас её хватит все молчуны могут одновременно начать диалог.

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Т.е. clientSocket.Close() будет достаточно в этом случае?

Comment: Думаю да.......